# DocuSign API Tab Required Attribute

Tags: rest, docusignapi

We are trying to modify existing tabs on a Docusign template with values from our database via the REST api.  However if we try to insert values without providing the 'required' attribute for a tab, we are seeing different results between the live API and demo API.

In the demo API (https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/) if we do not provide a required attribute, the tab will remain required/not required based on the existing value, which is the expected behavior.

In the live API (https://na2.docusign.net/restapi/v2/) if we do not provide a required attribute, the tab will always set itself to not be required.  This has the unfortunate result of all tabs in the template being not required unless we explicity provide the required attribute.

In both APIs, the template has the tabs we are setting marked as 'Required' by default.

We are able to work around this issue by providing the required attribute explicitly for tabs, but would be interested in knowing which behavior is intended.

Comment: I'd suggest that you contact DocuSign Support to report this issue, and the other issue you posted here on stackoverflow. Although you might get some feedback from a DocuSign rep here in stackoverflow, contacting Support directly would allow you to ensure that trackable cases/bugs get logged with DocuSign.

Comment: If you're saying that this is working as expected in demo but not in the live, then it's possible this was a previously addressed bug whose fix has been pushed to demo, and should be pushed to production soon.  However as Kim has suggested, contact DocuSign support - that's your best course of action.